# How do I change RichTextBox paragraph spacing?

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I am using a RichTextBox in WPF, and am trying to set the default paragraph spacing to 0 (so that there is no paragraph spacing).  While I could do this in XAML, I would like to achieve it programmatically if possible.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 224, accepted):

I did it **with style** (pun indented)

```
<RichTextBox  Margin="0,51,0,0" Name="mainTextBox" >
        <RichTextBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            </Style>
        </RichTextBox.Resources>
    </RichTextBox>
```

Comment: Nice solution, but won't you have to use code if you are formatting a selection, rather than all text in the box?

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I hate how RichTextBox inserts an extra "line" on Enter, I find it so unfamiliar, and was dreading the solution would be incredibly difficult. Boy am I relieved!

Comment: For anyone who finds this and is trying to do this against Windows Phone 7, the Margin property isn't available. `<LineBreak/>` ...

Answer (score 25):

Using Line Height

```
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();    
Paragraph p = rtb.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock as Paragraph;    
p.LineHeight = 10;
```

Comment: This is not enough if they can change font size.

Comment: I'm trying to get LineHeight, but it is always NaN. Any ideas?

Comment: This doesn't even answer the question. The asker wanted to know how to change _paragraph_ spacing, i.e. the space between each paragraph, not the _line_ spacing. You should be setting `p.Margin` not `p.LineHeight`

Answer (score 17):

Close, so you got the points.  Actually it turned out to be setting the margin,

```
p.Margin = new Thickness(0);
```

Answer (score 17):

For me on VS2017 in WPF works this:

```
 <RichTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="126" Margin="10,280,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="343" FontSize="14" Block.LineHeight="2"/>
```

The key is **Block.LineHeight="2"**

You can found this also in Properties view but you can't change below 6px from there.

Comment: "you can't change below 6px from there" - you can change it down to 1px by manually editing the value and not using the dropdown, which just contains commonly-used values starting from 6px.

Comment: [LineHeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.lineheight?view=netframework-4.8) inherited by `Paragraph` from `Block` determines the vertical distance between baselines when the paragraph has multiple lines. Indirectly it changes the space before and after the paragraph (the question), but this is not the solution. On the other hand `Paragraph.Margin` can adjust only the space before and after the paragraph.

Answer (score 6):

```
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
rtb.SetValue(Paragraph.LineHeightProperty, 1.0);
```

Comment: Doesn't work! Have you actually tested this yourself?

Comment: now the question is why is this working and why by default I have like another line of space between each line in single `AppenText`...

Answer (score 1):

```
<RichTextBox  Height="250" Width="500" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" IsReadOnly="True" >
    <Paragraph>
        XYZ
        <LineBreak />
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: This is a nice alternative to changing the margin of the paragraph, although it is not strictly what was asked for in the question.

Answer (score 1):

In C# 2008 WAP

```
richtextbox1.SelectionCharOffset =
    -1 * ( Convert.ToInt32(R223.Txt_Space_Before.Text) * 100);
```

or

```
richtextbox1.SelectionCharOffset =
    Convert.ToInt32(R223.Txt_Space_Before.Text) * 100;
```

can be used for Line Spacing.

This is the only way you can have line height spacing.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was posted before I even started coding but I found that simply setting `ShowSelectedMargin` to `true` did the trick

Comment: What kind of property is this? The only mention I find leads back to this answer.