# Decrease line spacing in a TextBlock / FlowDocument

Tags: wpf, fonts, word-wrap

Some fonts have a large amount of whitespace above and below the characters. Is there a way to correct for that, and tighten up the space between lines of a word-wrapped paragraph in WPF (in either a TextBlock or a FlowDocument)? Kind of like a negative margin between lines?

There's a `LineHeight` property on `Paragraph` and `TextBlock`, but it only seems to let you *increase* the spacing -- if you set it to a smaller value than the default, it's simply ignored.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Set the `LineHeight` like before, but change the `LineStackingStrategy` to `BlockLineHeight`

Comment: Works in UWP too!

Answer (score 4):

To exemplify @Joel's answer (which is still very useful 5 years later :P)

```
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Width="137" Height="47.96">
            <TextBlock Text="This is a very long text that gets cut because it is so long" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </Button>
        <Button Width="137" Height="47.96">
            <TextBlock Text="This is a very long text that doesn't cut thanks to @Joel" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" LineHeight="13"/>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325075/how-do-i-change-richtextbox-paragraph-spacing).

There are several different ways to fix the height.  The one that worked for me is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325075/how-do-i-change-richtextbox-paragraph-spacing/445897#445897) which sets the margin to 0.

Comment: That's for spacing between paragraphs. I'm asking about spacing between lines within a paragraph.