# How to decrease line height

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

I'm trying to reduce the line spacing by decrease LineHeight. But less than the default does not become.

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource font36}" LineHeight="6">List<LineBreak/>with parameters</TextBlock>
```

Comment: How much smaller do you want it to be? It also depends on your font size

Comment: 20% less. I know about font size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254512/decrease-line-spacing-in-a-textblock-flowdocument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the `LineStackingStrategy` to `BlockLineHeight` or `BaselineToBaseline`, like so:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource font36}" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" LineHeight="6" >List<LineBreak/>with parameters</TextBlock>
```

More info about line stacking strategy here: [What is Line Stacking Strategy in Silverlight TextBlock control?](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/05/what-is-line-stacking-strategy-in.html)