# WPF- "LineSpacing" in a TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock

I have a TextBlock I would like to pass a property of '**LineSpacing**'. The thing with using "**LineHeight**" with **LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"** is that it also applies the LineHeight to the segment before the first line:

[image: TextblockEx]

How can I manage to preserve said '**LineSpacing**' without modifying the **LineHeight** before the first line?

One thing I though might work is to separate each line in a **Paragraph** of a **FlowDocument**, since the **Paragraph** has a property *Spacing Before Line* and *Spacing After Line*.

Any help would be truly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**ANSWER**

It seems that you can use **LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight"** to avoid having leading on the first line. (Check answers below for full details).

*P.S. Thanks to Mitch for the revelation* :D

Comment: One easy thing you could do, is fake it. Just apply a small negative margin to the whole object to negate the line-spacing on the top and bottom. Like throw `Margin="0,-5"` on your `TextBlock` , such a short answer didn't think it warranted as more than a comment.

Comment: Not sure if this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325075/how-do-i-change-richtextbox-paragraph-spacing/445897#445897 applies to your question, or could be adapted, but might be worth a read.

Comment: Actually, that was my initial approach. I didn't want to keep up with it since it was causing me problems trying to calculate the margins for all the different options (Since the user can modify the **TextSize** and the **TextFont**, my calculations for the **LineHeight** method involves getting this 2 parameters to work in a function to calculate the **LineSpacing**, but down the line some combinations just don't quite fit (I believe is because of the decimals), but using another number format doesn't seem to work, either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that you can use `LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight"` to avoid having leading on the first line:

```
<TextBlock LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight" TextWrapping="Wrap" LineHeight="50">Lorem...</TextBlock>
```

Produces

[image: MaxHeight]

Comment: @Xanagandr, if this answers your question, you can mark it accepted by clicking the check-mark under the voting buttons.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work