# How to have a fixed line spacing in a textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, textbox

I am creating a software for note-taking. I created an image of a notebook with the lines, and etc. Now, I want to create a textbox (or rich text box, or whatever element that works) that will add the text exactly on top of each line.

[image: figure]

However, as the user types more than a few lines, the texts gets shifted a little bit on each line, ending up very weird.

I looked through many forums and questions in trying to have this fixed. Nothing helped. I'm developing it in Visual Studio, WPF project, C#. I want to add this control to the C# code, no XAML.

Comment: You need to adjust the property `FontSize`, and/or the attached properties `TextBlock.LineHeight` and [`TextBlock.LineStackingStrategyProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.linestackingstrategy(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Setting the `LineStackingStrategy` property.

```
p.LineStackingStrategy = LineStackingStrategy.BlockLineHeight;
```

If you need some spacing before the line also, like on starting of a paragraph then you can try setting the property as:

```
p.LineStackingStrategy = LineStackingStrategy.MaxHeight;
```

Check this Post: [WPF- "LineSpacing" in a TextBlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874453/wpf-linespacing-in-a-textblock)

Comment: @Rafael If the solution worked for you, you can accept the answer by clicking the tick mark  below the vote buttons.

Comment: Yeah, I did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for line height or paragraph margins:

```
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();    
Paragraph p = rtb.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock as Paragraph; 

p.LineHeight = /* Your height here */;
p.Margin = new Thickness(/* Your height here */);
```

Comment: Tried that before. Does not work. Keeps going out of the lines after a few lines.