# WPF RichTextBox puts 2 lines instead of 1 when clicking enter

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working with a RichTextBox, and whenever I click enter, the text skips one line and goes to other.

As following:
Text... (Clicks enter)

Text... (Goes here)

Instead of:
Text... (Clicks enter)
Text... (Goes here)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution: [How do I change RichTextBox paragraph spacing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325075/how-do-i-change-richtextbox-paragraph-spacing)

The issue you are seeing is related to Paragraph spacing.

Answer (score 0):

so late ...

lupu says right.

In my case, richTextBox's margin is Zero. but enter looks like input two lines.

so i find the reason.

Block's margin In Document(flowdocument) in richtextbox is Auto or has value (not zero).

when i changed block's margin is zero. then line looks normal like