# RichTextBox_logs.AppendText(Environment.NewLine); is returning two new lines?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, richtextbox

I do not know why but it always enters two new lines:

[image]

```cs
private void getMyIPAddress()
{
    String Address = "";
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        this.RichTextBox_logs.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
    });
    while (true)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            this.RichTextBox_logs.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            
            //this.RichTextBox_logs.ScrollToEnd();
        });
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://checkip.dyndns.com/");
        try
        {
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    Address = stream.ReadToEnd();
                }
                int first = Address.IndexOf("Address: ") + 9;
                int last = Address.IndexOf("</body>");               

                if (CurrentAddressHolder != Address.Substring(first, last - first))
                {
                    CurrentAddressHolder = Address.Substring(first, last - first);

                    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        this.textBox_ip.Text = CurrentAddressHolder;
                    });
                    
                }

                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    this.RichTextBox_logs.AppendText("IP is " + CurrentAddressHolder);
                });
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                this.RichTextBox_logs.AppendText(e.ToString());
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to multi-threading and I'm not sure if it affected the syntax to the new line.

Any inputs or code revisions/improvements are highly welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Describe what do you **_"always enters two new lines"_**, please. Because of on the attached screen shot is only one line is added all the time - `IP is 49.145.41.47`.

Comment: If there really are two returns added each time, have you tried putting debug log after `this.RichTextBox_logs.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);` and `this.RichTextBox_logs.AppendText("IP is " + CurrentAddressHolder);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your problem is line spacing.

**Solution one:**

Instead of the `AppendText()` method use the following method to add a text line to the `RichTextBox`:

```cs
public void AddText(RichTextBox rtb, string message, double spacing = 4)
{
    var paragraph = new Paragraph() { LineHeight = spacing };
    paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run(message));
    rtb.Document.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
}
```

With this method you will able to change line spacing between paragraphs programmatically by setting the LineHeight value.

When using this approach don't necessary to add the `Environment.NewLine`. Each block (paragraph) will automatically formatted as different line.

**Solution two:**

Try to change the paragraph margin (see the following post https://stackoverflow.com/a/445897/6630084):

```xml
<RichTextBox x:Name="RichTextBox_logs" >
    <RichTextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </RichTextBox.Resources>
    ...
<RichTextBox>
```